# When I name columns in dataframe it deletes my data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a pandas DataFrame that holds various summary statistics for several variables in my dataset. I want to name the columns of the dataframe, but every time I try it deletes all my data. Here is what it looks like without column names:

```
MIN = df.min(axis=0, numeric_only=True)
MAX = df.max(axis=0, numeric_only=True)
RANGE = MAX-MIN
MEAN = df.mean(axis=0, numeric_only=True)
MED = df.median(axis=0, numeric_only=True)

sum_stats = pd.concat([MIN, MAX, RANGE, MEAN, MED], axis=1)
sum_stats = pd.DataFrame(data=sum_stats)
sum_stats
```

My output looks like this:
[image]

But for some reason when I add column names:

```
sum_stats = pd.concat([MIN, MAX, RANGE, MEAN, MED], axis=1)
columns = ['MIN', 'MAX', 'RANGE', 'MEAN', 'MED']
sum_stats = pd.DataFrame(data=sum_stats, columns=columns)
sum_stats
```

My output becomes this:
[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for the `columns` parameter of the [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) constructor:

> [...] If data contains column labels, will perform column selection instead.

That means that, if the data passed is already a dataframe, for example, the `columns` parameter will act as a list of columns to select from the data.

If you change `columns` to equal a list of some columns that already exist in the dataframe that you're using, e.g. `columns=[1, 4]`, you'll see that the resulting dataframe only contains those two columns, copied from the original dataframe.

---

Instead, you can assign the columns after you create the dataframe:

```
sum_stats.columns = ['MIN', 'MAX', 'RANGE', 'MEAN', 'MED']
```